# Solve $\int \frac{\arctan(x)}{x^3} dx$ without partial fractions

Tags: calculus, integration

So I'm trying to solve for the indefinite integral $$\int \frac{\arctan(x)}{x^3}\, dx$$

Here is what I tried:
Use integration by parts:
$$\int v\,du = vu - \int u\,dv$$
Let $v = \arctan(x)\\$
Let $dv = \frac{dx}{1 + x^2}.\\$
Let $du = x^3\, dx.\\$
Let $u = -\frac{1}{2x^2}.\\$

$$ -\frac{\arctan(x)}{2x^2} + \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{x^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + x^2} \,dx$$

Now I'm sort of stuck, and since we haven't been taught partial fractions, I'm not sure how to proceed. Would someone mind explaining how to approach this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can "avoid" partial fractions by adding and subtracting an $x^2$ in the numerator of $\frac{1}{x^2(1+x^2)}$

Comment: You don't really need to have been  taught partial fractions to observe that $\;\dfrac  1{x^2(1+x^2)}=\dfrac 1{x^2}-\dfrac 1{1+x^2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. One may just write
$$
\frac{1}{x^2(1 + x^2)}=\frac{(1+x^2)-x^2}{x^2(1 + x^2)}=\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{1 + x^2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks that intermediate step was actually really helpful!